# Laravel: How can I get all dates between date ranges and all dates within date ranges separately?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, date-range, php-carbon

I try to get all dates between *n* date ranges and additionally all dates within these date ranges.

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $startDate = new Carbon('2019-11-20');
    $endDate = new Carbon('2019-11-27');
    $all_dates = array();
    while ($startDate->lte($endDate)) {
        $all_dates[] = $startDate->toDateString();
        $startDate->addDay();
    }
    return $all_dates;
}
```

My output looks good. That’s exactly what I need:

```
["2019-11-20","2019-11-21","2019-11-22","2019-11-23","2019-11-24","2019-11-25","2019-11-26","2019-11-27"]
```

I tried different ways passing my date ranges from my database to my function. But it's not working. In my table are two important fields:

```
$query = DB::select('start_date', 'end_date')->get();
```

1: What can I do to get the same result like in my example?

2: How can I ignore in my output the start date and end date of each date range? I just need the dates within a date range.

**UPDATE:**

So I've found a way for the first question. My table has currently two rows:

```
id | start_date | end_date
 1 | 2019-11-22 | 2019-11-24
 2 | 2019-11-26 | 2019-11-28
```

I extended my working function with two database queries (one for each field) and combined these with a loop.

```
public function index()
{
    $query_start_dates = Bookings::select('start_date')->get();
    $start_dates = array();
    $multiple_start_date = json_decode($query_start_dates, true);
    foreach($multiple_start_date as $single_start_date)
    $start_dates[] = implode(', ', $single_start_date);

    $query_end_dates = Bookings::select('end_date')->get();
    $end_dates = array();
    $multiple_end_date = json_decode($query_end_dates, true);
    foreach($multiple_end_date as $single_end_date)
    $end_dates[] = implode(', ', $single_end_date);

    $all_dates = array();

    foreach(array_combine($start_dates, $end_dates) as $f => $n) {
        $startDate = new Carbon($f);
        $endDate = new Carbon($n);
        while ($startDate->lte($endDate)) {
            $all_dates[] = $startDate->toDateString();
            $startDate->addDay();
        }
    }

    return $all_dates;
}
```

My new output:

```
["2019-11-22","2019-11-23","2019-11-24","2019-11-26","2019-11-27","2019-11-28"]
```

It doesn't look smart, but it works perfectly ;) Now, I just need a solution for my second question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have solved your first question. I'm now trying to help u out for the last one. Again there are so many ways to solve it, the easy ( though not smart but floats the boat ;) )  way:

You can simply slice the first and the last element from your date array. usually , you may use array shift and pop

```
array_shift($all_dates);
array_pop($all_dates);
```

you can use array_slice as well but I think shift and pop is better than slice. it performs better.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it looks like a filter. Finally I need to output every single date of a date range. Each row in my table (reservations) has a start date and end date. That's why I don't think that your approach is the right way?

Comment: I assume you need all the dates only right ? you can use pluck instead get than. try using pluck(). I've edited my ans. pluck will return you the specific column value you want in an array

Comment: Thanks! I didn't find a useable way with pluck. Have a look at my update. Maybe you've an idea for the second questions or some other improvements for the first?

Comment: Check my answer bro. edited :) really hope it helps

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much!! That's a really simple way :)